Does PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest`'s dealing with additional cookies gotten from another request, beyond `SessionVariable`?
Does Invoke-WebRequest -Websession Variable store cookies received by subsequent Invoke-WebRequest calls?
I.e., If I call Invoke-WebRequest -Websession Variable, and get a first set of cookies. Then Invoke-WebRequest -Sessionstore $Variable, does the second Invoke-WebRequest store it's received cookies in $Variable, also?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4 ... Ctrl+F, search for 'Cookie' and then read every section where the word if found. What version of PowerShell.

PS5, but with respect, I have already read through that and found nothing conclusive, hence the question.

Okay, not a problem, as per the content on that link, the answer if no, the parameters to use for this are -SessionVariable or -WebSession, the issue might be the parameter used. This should be relatively simple to test and confirm, just pointing out the obvious things stated in the MS post. Use one of those parameters to use a cookie again along with other values those may contain. You listed -Sessionstore so -sessionstore specifically is not the parameter to use if it's even applicable.

I know that a single use of Sessionstore (case in my experience doesn't change parameter name functionality) stores variables that can be pushed into the next Invoke-Webrequest -Websession, by my code that initiated this question. I was hoping someone could tell me if cookies received in the Invoke-Webrequest -Websession use of the stored cookies, saves the new ones into the variable both use.
